# Problema al obtener el value de un select con jquery

Tags: jquery, select

Se supone al cambiar alguno de los select deberia recorrer todos los select y tomar sus valores pero siempre toma el primer  de cada uno..

```js
function cantperson() {
    var habs = 2;
    var i = 1;
    var cantadult = 0;
    var cantchild = 0;
    var total = 0;
    while (i <= habs) {
        var select = document.getElementById("cantadult"+i);
        alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
        i = i + 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<select id="cantadult1" name="cantadult1" onchange="cantperson();">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>     
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
            <select id="cantadult2" name="cantadult2" onchange="cantperson();">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>     
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
          <option value="11">11</option>
          <option value="12">12</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: Pero eso es exactamente lo que hace tu código toma la opción seleccionada de cada select, ¿O quieres que haga otra cosa? Y otro punto, dices que el problema es con jQuery pero veo Javascript puro, ¿Estás seguro que es jQuery y no Javascript?

Comment: Y ya que andamos en esas te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] termina el [tour] para que ganes tu primera medalla :D

Comment: 1. no aplicas JQuery, 2. tu código toma los valores seleccionados de cada select.

Comment: Es que es justo el problema estoy haciendo un proyecto en wordpress y alli siempre me toma el valor del primero <option>, incluso en el emulador de stackoverflow me lo hace bien me estoy percantando T_T

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no veo donde aplicas Jquery en tu codigo, te recomiendo leer mas sobre esta libreria, para el caso que expones mi respuesta para hacerlo seria algo como esto.

**HTML**

```
<h3>Obtener el valor de un select en jquery</h3>
<label>Select Numeros 1</label>
<select id="cantadult1" name="cantadult1" onchange="cantperson(this)">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>                    
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <label>Select Numeros 2</label>
    <select id="cantadult2" name="cantadult2" onchange="cantperson(this)">
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>                    
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                    </select>
```

JAVA SCRIPT

```
 function cantperson(element) {
  var n = element.value; 
  console.log(n); //imprimes el valor del select
 }
```

Saludos,
Espero haberte ayudado de alguna manera